# I'm trying to understand what exactly the SNR calculation does in Python

Tags: python, syntax, frequency

following I have embedded the code which shows several signals (4 rPPG signals) in the frequency domain (PSD).

```
 def pow2db(x):
    """returns the corresponding decibel (dB) value for a power value x.

    The relationship between power and decibels is:

    .. math::    X_{dB} = 10 * \log_{10}(x)

    .. doctest::

        >>> from spectrum import pow2db
        >>> x = pow2db(0.1)
        >>> x
        -10.0
    """
    return 10 * log10(x)

# calculate SNR from Pulse - Signal
def SNR(bvp, fps, hr):

    #BVPSNR Estimates the signal-to-noise ratio of the blood volume pulse
    # signal. Adapted from the method by G. de Haan, TBME, 2013.
    # SNR calculated as the ratio (in dB) of power contained within +/- 0.1 Hz
    # of the reference heart rate frequency and +/- 0.2 of its first
    # harmonic and sum of all other power between 0.7 and 2 Hz.
    # Adapted from the method by G. de Haan, TBME, 2013
    #
    #   Inputs:
    #       BVP                     = A BVP timeseries.
    #       FS                      = The sample rate of the BVP time series (Hz/fps).
    #       HR                      = The reference heart rate (Hz/fps).
    #       PlotTF                  = Boolean to turn plotting results on or off.
    #
    #  Outputs:
    #       SNR                     = Blood Volume Pulse Signal-to-Noise Ratio.
    #

    HR_F = hr/60
    Nyquist = fps/2
    FResBPM = 0.5
    N = (60*2*Nyquist)/FResBPM
    print(N)

    f_set, Pxx_den = welch(bvp, fps, window='hann', nperseg=N)
    GTMask1 = (f_set >= HR_F-0.15) & (f_set <= HR_F+0.15)
    GTMask2 = (f_set >= HR_F-0.3) & (f_set <= HR_F+0.3)

    SPower = sum(Pxx_den[GTMask1|GTMask2])
    FMask2 = (f_set >= 0.7)&(f_set <= 2)
    AllPower = sum(Pxx_den[FMask2])

    #fig3 = plt.figure(3)
    #plt.semilogy(f_set, f_psd)
    figure100 = plt.figure(100)
    plt.semilogy(f_set,Pxx_den)
    plt.title('welch Power Spectrum for SNR calculation / ROIs')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    plt.ylabel('Power (dB)')

    return pow2db(SPower/(AllPower-SPower))
```

for a better understanding I have the following figure

[image]

My understanding is that SNR of each signal in this range (+/- 0.15 and +/- 0.3) is looked at and identified that in this frequency range (1.1 Hz) no other signals have the same signal strength. Ultimately represented by the SNR.

I'm probably wrong. I just didn't understand the look at the masks and the connection between the overall strength. I would be very happy about your opinion!

*I can't get any wiser from the explanation of the comment in the source code either.*

Comment: Did you google the article from the comment? De Haan 2013

Comment: yea i did, but the developer just adaptet the methology. De Haan uses different algorithmn but based on BVP signals.

Comment: it would be helpful to know what exactly happens to the signals in relation to the masks. Logic and purpose aside.